# Copy data from one worksheet to another based on column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro that will copy data from one worksheet to another based on column headers. Lets say in ws1 there are three columns: "product", "name", "employer" and the ws2: "product", "name", "region".

So i want the macro to do all the copying as in my original file i have over 100 column headers and it will be very time consuming for to do it myself.

I have written two macros without succes. VBA is something I cant understand for quite some time. but still managed to write something, hope you can tell me if i am going in the right direction.

this is v1

```
Sub Copy_rangev1()

Dim Ws1 As Worksheet, Ws2 As Worksheet
Dim SourceRange As Range, CopyRange As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer

Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set SourceRange = Ws2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set CopyRange = Ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If SourceRange.Cells(i, 1).Value = CopyRange.Cells(i, 1) Then
       SourceRange.Cells(i + 1 & lastrow, 1).Copy Destination:=CopyRange.Range("a" & lastrow)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

this v2:

```
Sub Copyrangev2()

Dim SourceRange As Worksheet
Dim CopyRange As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Integer
Set SourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set CopyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
Dim i As Integer

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To 100
    If SourceRange.Range(1, i).Value = CopyRange.Range(1, i) Then
       SourceRange.Range(1, i).Offset(1, 0).Copy Destination:=CopyRange.Range(1, i)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

My code is a mess, but if you want me to provide any more details leave a comment, i dont expect you to given a fully workable code, a good explanation and few suggestions will do. Thanks

Comment: Two questions: (1) Are the headers in both worksheets in exactly the same order; (2) Are you copying every column from one worksheet to the other or is it only certain columns?

Comment: Hey @alex P, no thats the problem, if theyr were in the same order i would try do it manually. on top of that there might be columns in one ws which are not in the other ws, in this case I would need to count the last coulmn and paste the data next to it. I think the macro should copy the data by rows not by cells, to make sure everything is corrected and sorted. and yea i am copying every column. hope its clear but do ask me if u need more info. thanks dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? This code works as follows

- Iterate across each column header in `ws1` and see if a matching
  header exists in `ws2`
- If a match is found, copy the column contents across to the relevant column in `ws2`

This will work *irrespective* of column order. You can change the range references to suit.

```
Sub CopyHeaders()
    Dim header As Range, headers As Range
    Set headers = Worksheets("ws1").Range("A1:Z1")

    For Each header In headers
        If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
            Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("ws2").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
    Dim headers As Range
    Set headers = Worksheets("ws2").Range("A1:Z1")
    GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)), Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Hey alex, thanks. Your code is really good but forgot to mention that the range in the sheet 1 is not empty, and I would like it to be pasted to the empty row, you get what i mean?

Comment: the code basically overwrites the data in the range, instead i want it to be pasted to the next empty row.

Comment: Try `Destination:=Worksheets("ws2").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value)).end(xlDown).offset(1,0)`

Comment: Hey alex, I would appreciate if you could me explain how the function procedure works here. How is it being able to match the headers even if you dont specify the worksheets, you only tell the range. I want to know, so that i can add another line of code where if some column headers dont match, the vba will add one more column and paste the data.

Comment: The worksheets *are* specified i.e. `ws1` in the sub and `ws2` in the function. If a column is not matched the function returns 0. In your case, extend the `if` statement so when a column is not matched it adds a new column. I'd use `.end(xlRight).Column + 1` to get the next available column. Have a try...

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CustomColumnCopy()

    Dim wsOrigin As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngFnd As Range
    Dim rngDestSearch As Range
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim rownum As Range

    Set wsOrigin = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet2")

    Const ORIGIN_ROW_HEADERS = 1
    Const DEST_ROW_HEADERS = 1

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       wsOrigin.UsedRange.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    For Each rownum In wsOrigin.UsedRange

        Set rngDestSearch = Intersect(wsDest.UsedRange, wsDest.Rows(DEST_ROW_HEADERS))

        For Each cel In Intersect(wsOrigin.UsedRange, wsOrigin.Rows(ORIGIN_ROW_HEADERS))
        On Error Resume Next

            Set rngFnd = rngDestSearch.Find(cel.Value)

            If Not rngFnd Is Nothing Then

               wsDest.Cells(rownum.Cells.row, rngFnd.Column).Value = wsOrigin.Cells(rownum.Cells.row, cel.Column).Value

            End If

        On Error GoTo 0

        Set rngFnd = Nothing

        Next cel

    Next rownum

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    Application.GoTo wsDest.Range("A1")
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

    Dim keyRange As Range

    Set keyRange = Range("A1")
    wsDest.Range("A" & LastRow(wsDest) + 1).Sort Key1:=keyRange, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Comment: It is preferable to include an explanation to your code and especially in what way it differs from the accepted answer